# Is there a way to clarify the true and false statements in this JS?

Tags: javascript, boolean, truthiness

I've been working on learning JS, and I can't seem to figure out why my boolean values keep coming back either always true or always false.

So I believe I understand the basics of the truthy/falsy situation in JS, but I can't seem to get it right. I know that there are data type issues, (can't make different data types do different things).

```js
function lastCharacter(char1, char2) {
  if (char1[-1] === '' && char2[-1] === '') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(lastCharacter('apple', 'pumpkine'));
```

Or

```js
function lastCharacter(char1, char2) {
  if (char1[-1] === char2[-1]) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(lastCharacter('apple', 'pumpkina'));
```

Define a function `lastCharacter` that accepts two strings as arguments.
`lastCharacter` should return true if both strings end with the same character.
Otherwise, `lastCharacter` should return false.

They either return always true or always false. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `char1[-1]` is always `undefined`; it does not give you the last character of the string, in particular.

Comment: ... one of those pitfalls when coming from python

Comment: `console.log(char1[-1], char2[-1])` What are you expecting it to return? The last character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no negative array indexes in JavaScript, instead of `char1[-1]` you have to use `char1[char1.length - 1]`.

Accessing one of a strings characters (e.g. `"abc[1]`) will always have a length of 1, it will never be equal to `""`. Your second function makes more sense.

Also

```
 if(condition) { return true; } else { return false; }
```

is equal to

```
 return condition;
```

Comment: *"A string chracter will always have a length of 1, it will never be equal to ""."* o_O

Comment: @ninaScholz `"abc"[1]` ? (yes, or `undefined`)

Comment: @NinaScholz I think he means "a string that's the result of using valid array indexing on a longer string", so `"hello"[1]` is always 1 character long.

Answer (score 3):

You need a different method for getting the last character of a string, preferably with [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and a negative value for getting the last one. Then compare and return the result.

```js
function lastCharacter(string1, string2) {
    return string1.slice(-1) === string2.slice(-1);
}

console.log(lastCharacter('apple', 'pumpkine'));
```

A comparison between taking the last character of an empty string by using an index `-1` which returns `undefined` and `slice`, which returns an empty string.

```js
var x = '';

console.log('#' + x.slice(-1) + '#');
console.log('#' + x[x.length -1] + '#');
```

Comment: `string[string.length - 1]` saves a function call :) *edit* oops except it's `undefined` for empty strings!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use slice

```js
function lastCharacter(char1, char2) {
  return char1.slice(-1) === char2.slice(-1)
}

console.log(lastCharacter('apple', 'pumpkina'));
console.log(lastCharacter('apple', 'snake'));
```

Or you can just access the last index

```js
function lastCharacter(char1, char2) {
  return char1[char1.length-1] === char2[char2.length-1]
}

console.log(lastCharacter('apple', 'pumpkina'));
console.log(lastCharacter('apple', 'snake'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The notation `[-1]` does not implicitly mean "one character from the end of the string" in JavaScript. You can use `str[str.length - 1]`. (If you expect possible empty source strings, you'd want to check for that too to avoid ending up with exactly the same problem.)

Instead of an `if/else` that returns either `true` or `false`, just return the results of the logical expression:

```
    return char1[char1.length - 1] === '' && char2[char2.length - 1] === '';
```

Both the `===` comparisons return either `true` or `false` anyway, so the overall expression value has to be one of those. In general however if you want to make absolutely sure that you end up with a boolean, you can prefix an expression with `!!` to force the standard JavaScript "truthy-falsy" evaluation:

```
    return !!(expression);
```